# virtual environment can't start python -- "No such file or directory"

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, virtualenv, virtual-environment

I have created a venv using Pycharm.  On the PyCharm terminal, everything works fine -- I can activate the venv, and start python normally.

When I exit PyCharm and go to the normal linux terminal, it doesn't work.

First I go to my directory:

```
$ cd /home/me/PycharmProjects/virtualenvs/my_project/bin/
```

Then I activate the venv

```
$ source ./activate
```

I check my python file

```
(my_project) $ which python

/home/me/PycharmProjects/virtualenvs/my_project/bin/python
```

But when I try to invoke python, it fails

```
$ python

/home/me/PycharmProjects/virtualenvs/my_project/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

Am I missing something or is this a problem with PyCharm?  This is on Linux Mint, recently installed with minimal changes.

Comment: You should set Environment variable on your windows system to use python. Use this link to set python path and try again https://www.pythoncentral.io/add-python-to-path-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/

Comment: what is displayed when you do: ls -l /home/me/PycharmProjects/virtualenvs/my_project/bin/python

Comment: @SuhasJadhav Where do you see "windows" in the question? As for "environment variables" they seem to be set as `which` works properly.

Comment: @Lingster when I do   `ls -l /home/me/PycharmProjects/virtualenvs/my_project/bin/python`   I get `-rwxr-xr-x 1 me me 12672 Jun 10 20:06 python`